# Unable to connect to browser using ruby selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I tried to run some basic automated tests using ruby selenium webdriver. The same code works perfectly on my home computer, but fails on my work computer which is behind a proxy (which doesn't require authentication).

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => 'default'

The error I get is:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.24.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in `create_response': unexpected response, code=
403, content-type="text/html" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}PRE{font-family:sans-serif}--></STYLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
<P>
While trying to retrieve the URL:
<A HREF="http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session">http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session</A>
<P>
The following error was encountered:
<UL>
<LI>
<STRONG>
Access Denied.
</STRONG>
<P>
Access control configuration prevents your request from
being allowed at this time.  Please contact your service provider if
you feel this is incorrect.
</UL>
```

The browser opens with correct profile, but resulting driver variable is nil. I even tried to manually setup the proxy on the profile with no luck.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably have HTTP_PROXY (or http_proxy) set in your environment. The next release of selenium-webdriver (2.25) will also honor NO_PROXY/no_proxy (which you can then set to NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1). Until then you can remove the proxy from the Ruby environment before launching the browser:

```
ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = ENV['http_proxy'] = nil
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

If you need the proxy configured for Firefox to communicate with the outside world, you could try something like this:

```
proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(:http => ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] || ENV['http_proxy'])
ENV['HTTP_PROXY'] = ENV['http_proxy'] = nil
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :proxy => proxy
```

Comment: I'm using selenium-webdriver 2.26.0, setting NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Usage of selenium-webdriver behind proxy has browser related specific. In short, you need to find a way of passing proxy settings to the browser instance created by webdriver.

Below is a code that works with Firefox.

```
#Firefox keeps proxy settings in profile.
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new( :http => "192.168.1.1:3128")
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
puts driver.title
driver.quit
```

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
ENV['NO_PROXY']="127.0.0.1"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://google.com"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Maybe you can add some text to explain your answer ?!