# Selenium Ruby 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, geckodriver

Here is my Code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class TestSelenium

  def initialize
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
  end
end
```

And here is my error message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:88:in `create_response': unexpected response, code=500, content-type="text/html" (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in 'request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in 'call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:164:in 'execute'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:97:in 'create_session'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/marionette/driver.rb:50:in 'initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31:in 'new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31:in 'new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in 'for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:85:in 'for'
    from test_selenium.rb:6:in 'initialize'
    from test_selenium.rb:11:in 'new'
    from test_selenium.rb:11:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/11190317/4758119

Comment: You are doing this on a server or a machine with UI/Desktop?

Comment: Doing it on a RHEL 7 VM, it has a UI and desktop